# Is my overview of .Net Data Providers and ADO.Net correct?

Tags: .net, ado.net

Recently I had to type up some documentation on .net data providers and ado.net.  I am trying to get feedback on my findings.  Please review and provide corrections or opinions.

**Summary**
This is a high level summary of the basic .Net API’s for interacting with a database.  As a developer with mainly a Java and PHP background I was unclear about how ADO.Net related to OleDb and I had no idea what was meant by the term “.Net Data Provider”. I created this because the msdn documentation is HEAVILY focused on ADO.Net and does not give a clear picture of how the many namespaces, interfaces, and classes interact.

**.Net Data Provider**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=VS.71).aspx
- A .NET Framework data provider is
  used for connecting to a database,
  executing commands, and retrieving
  results. Those results are either
  processed directly, or placed in an
  ADO.NET DataSet.
- What that actually means is that a
  .Net Data Provider implements the
  interfaces defined in the System.Data
  namespace.
- A .Net Data Provider is similar to a
  JDBC driver in Java

**System.Data**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx
  This page contains text that makes
  you believe that ADO.Net is the CORE
  part of .Net data access, however the
  reality is that ADO.Net is the
  highest level of data access and is
  built upon the .Net Data Providers
  that implement the interfaces in the
  System.Data.
- In my opinion it almost seems like
  microsoft is trying to hide how
  database connections work, so that
  users are trapped using controls
  provided by visual studio. The
  System.Data namesapce contains
  Interfaces that need to be defined by
  ALL .Net Data Providers

**System.Data Core Interfaces**

- IDbConnection
- IDbCommand
- IDataAdapter
- IDataReader

**Examples of System.Data Implementations**

- The following namespaces include classes
  that implement the core “.Net Data
  Provider” interfaces defined in
  System.Data
- System.Data.SqlClient
- System.Data.OleDb
- System.Data.Odbc
- IBM.Data.DB2
- ByteFX.Data.MySqlClient

**ADO.Net**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y4ybxw(v=VS.71).aspx
- ADO.Net is a database query and
  manipulation API built on top of the
  basic .Net Data Provider classes.
  ADO.Net focuses on disconnected,
  multi-tier database interaction.
- In my opinion the core ADO.Net
  classes should be in a separate
  namespace like System.Data.ADO just
  for the sake of clarity.

**ADO.Net Core Classes**

- DataSet
- DataTable
- DataColumn
- DataRelation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Data is the "package" that contains everything for working with "Data providers" in .NET. It is true that ADO, is one strategy for working with data, but it is the primary strategy in .NET.

ADO is less about specific DB technologies (as it is not necessarily meant to be a database specific technology) and more about data relationships. The terms: Set, Table, Column, Row and Relationship are well understood modeling terms and ADO.NET makes them first class objects in the .NET space.

Data providers provide low-level implementation specific details for supporting the core ADO.NET concepts (tables, rows, etc) and are meant to abstract away the direct implementation details of how to connect to a data provider. For instance, you should be able to, with relatively little effort, swap out a Jet Data provider, with a Oracle Data provider, in terms of DataTables, DataRows, and DataColumns (query details aside) such that your code is minimally impacted by the change. Why is this important? Because it means you can work with non-homogenous data sources with similar command semantics (i.e. you can work with excel spreadsheets and MySql dbs in the same app with the same objects). This makes reuse and repurposing very easy and very straight-forward.

As a general view you can think of the system this way:

1. The .NET Data provider is where you get your data from. You will need to import from System.Data each provider that your app uses
2. The ADO.NET classes are the concepts you will be working with Tables, Rows, Columns, etc. These have nothing to do with queries, indexes, etc. Those are provider details
3. Your app should only rarely (I would say never, but there are always exceptions) need to be aware of the Provider and instead focus on consuming and producing DataSets, DataTables, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps a lot.  I wish the MSDN docs were this clear.  My background in Java and php made it hard to relate to ADO.Net(DataTable specifically).  I totally agree about programming independent of a specific provider.  You can do that even without the DataTable and DataSet classes, which as you said are independnet of providers because they are concrete classes in the System.Data namespace.  If you hide the "Data provider" implementation behind the interfaces in the System.Data namespace you can change your provider at anytime.  Thx for the reply.

Comment: @Welzie its true you dont need to use the DataTable and DataSet as the DataReader provides a much easier to understand DB reader semantic, but DataTable (DT) and DataSet (DS) are meant to convey a different meaning than a one-way movement of data. The DT and DS are meant to provide proxy implementations of data usage and give you a disconnected interface to your data provider, such that the DT/DS "act" as the database, and the underlying details are not important to consuming code. I think in practice this is not how the DT and DS are used though, usually they are just containers for data.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to:

> In my opinion it almost seems like
>   microsoft is trying to hide how
>   database connections work, so that
>   users are trapped using controls
>   provided by visual studio.

The existence of 3rd party providers does not support the idea that MS is trying to "trap" us into anything.

Hiding "how database connections work" is a kind of abstraction, and is not subversive.

Comment: Understood, but hiding how a crucial part of a system happens limits a developers understanding.  In reality at this level everything is an abstraction.  If you only learn the ADO.Net api and don't learn about connections, transactions, commands I feel a developers scope on database interaction is extremely limited.  Thx for the reply.